# Cannot restart Sonar server after installing SonarJS plugin

Tags: sonarqube, sonarjs

1. cloned sonarjs plugin from [github | sonarjs plugin](https://github.com/SonarSource/SonarJS.git)
2. created jar file via, mvn install command
3. copied jar file into sonarqube-5.6.6/extensions/plugins/
4. Now, when trying to start sonar server, it stops with following message:

> Running SonarQube...
>   wrapper  | --> Wrapper Started as Console
>   wrapper  | Launching a JVM...
>   jvm 1    | Wrapper (Version 3.2.3) http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.org
>   jvm 1    |   Copyright 1999-2006 Tanuki Software, Inc.  All Rights Reserved.
>   jvm 1    |
>   jvm 1    | 2017.11.29 22:17:20 INFO  app[o.s.a.AppFileSystem] Cleaning or creating temp directory /home/sd2labs/    mycomputer/sonarqube-5.6.6/temp
>   jvm 1    | 2017.11.29 22:17:20 INFO  app[o.s.p.m.JavaProcessLauncher] Launch process[es]: /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java -Djava.awt.headless=true -Xmx1G -Xms256m -Xss256k -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -XX:+UseParNewGC -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=75 -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Djava.io.tmpdir=/home/sd2labs/mycomputer/sonarqube-5.6.6/temp -javaagent:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/management-agent.jar -cp ./lib/common/*:./lib/search/* org.sonar.search.SearchServer /home/sd2labs/mycomputer/sonarqube-5.6.6/temp/    sq-process8688307264383931251properties
>   jvm 1    | 2017.11.29 22:17:28 INFO  app[o.s.p.m.Monitor] Process[es] is up
>   jvm 1    | 2017.11.29 22:17:28 INFO  app[o.s.p.m.JavaProcessLauncher] Launch process[web]: /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java -Djava.awt.headless=true -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Djruby.management.enabled=false -Djruby.compile.invokedynamic=false -Xmx512m -Xms128m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Djava.io.tmpdir=/home/sd2labs/mycomputer/sonarqube-5.6.6/temp -javaagent:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/management-agent.jar -cp ./lib/common/*:./lib/server/*:/home/sd2labs/mycomputer/sonarqube-5.6.6/lib/jdbc/mysql/mysql-connector-java-5.1.35.jar org.sonar.server.app.WebServer /home/sd2labs/mycomputer/sonarqube-5.6.6/temp/    sq-process1772881744825311451properties
>   jvm 1    | 2017.11.29 22:17:33 INFO  app[o.s.p.m.Monitor] Process[es] is stopping
>   jvm 1    | 2017.11.29 22:17:34 INFO  app[o.s.p.m.Monitor] Process[es] is stopped
>   wrapper  | <-- Wrapper Stopped

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: No error entries in the other SonarQube log files?

Comment: My bad, I was just copying wrong jar file.

Answer (score 1):

Most probably you have 2 plugin version for SonarJS in your /extensions/plugins/. Remove the one, you don't need (the one provided by default)